# How to embed music player widget on website like myspace in html?

Tags: html, css, audio-player, myspace

How can I embed a music player widget to my website like Myspace? I already have the music player code, but I want it to be fixed in the header or footer whenever I move from page to page, it won't interfere with the music play as on Myspace. Anyone can help me with a HTML code to do so please, so I could wrap it around my music player code?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vain.

You could create a `music.php` file and paste the music player widget into that, then use the following PHP on the pages where you want the music player to appear:

```
<?php include ("music.php")?>
```